# Dynamic column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to work with locale:

In *routes.rb* I have:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|ro|ru/ do
  resources :catalogs
end
```

In *application_controller.rb* I have

```
# tell the I18n library where to find your translations
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}')]

# set default locale to something other than :en
I18n.default_locale = :en

before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

In the database I have a table with columns: catalog_name_en; catalog_name_ro and catalog_name_ru

In the view *list.html.erb* I add this code:

```
<% @catalogs.each do |catalog| %>

    <tr>
        <td class="center"><%= catalog.id %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= "catalog.catalog_name#{locale}" %> </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

In the html page I see only "catalog.catalog_name_en", but not the value for the column catalog_name_en .
Help me PLZ.

Comment: I believe you should flag (use the "checkmark") one answer as accepted now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using:

```
<%= catalog.attributes["catalog_name_#{locale}"] %>
```

Or a shorter, but equivalent (as noted in comments):

```
<%= catalog["catalog_name_#{locale}"] %>
```

Comment: Forgot underscore `catalog_name_#{locale}` ;)

Comment: @jdoe Edited answer accordingly. Although, the underscore is **not** in the OP's sample code...

Comment: And FYI: you can ommit the `.attrbibutes` part. Just use: `catalog["..."]`. Cool, yeah? :)

Comment: @AlexandruPara it does work, but I usually consider being more explicit about what I'm doing - call it a Java-ism?

Comment: @Romain, Rails isn't where explicit way is encouraged. Are you sure you've picked the correct framework? :))) We like here being treated as magicians!

Comment: @jdoe I like being treated as magician. I love ruby & rails. But I work in a large company - making it easy to passing the codebase to n00bs who don't know sh#t about the framework is actually a very important part of the job.

Comment: So, you're writing less magnificent code just to make sure that some newbie won't have a headache? What a hero you are! Enroll me in your company! )))

Comment: @jdoe Out code is magnificent in various ways, though. And we don't make sure the newbie doesn't get a headache. We make sure the newbie doesn't come asking questions every five minutes - saving US a headache :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
catalog.send("catalog_name_#{locale}")
```

Comment: Thanks, `catalog.send("catalog_name_#{locale}")`
this works too.